# Having syntax errors with if statements

Tags: r

I have the following question:

In the imported data frame, I need to create a new column named “profit_margin_flag” whose value is computed as follows [profit margin = Profit / Sales].

a.If the profit margin is negative, the new column should have the value “negative”.

b.If the profit margin is positive and less than 10%, the new column should have the value “low margin”.

c.If the profit margin is 10% or more, but less than 25%, the new column should have the value “standard margin”.

d.If the profit margin is 50% or more, the new column should have the value “high margin”.

I coded this:

```
orders$profit_margin_flag <- orders$Profit/orders$Sales
n <- nrow(orders)
`for (i in (1:n))`
{
if(orders$profit_margin_flag[i] < 0)
{orders$profit_margin_flag[i] <- "negative"}
  else if(orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >0 && <.10)
    {orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "low margin"}
else if(orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >= .10 && < .25)
  {orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "standard margin"}
 else if(orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >= .50) 
   {orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "high margin"}
}
```

I receive this error:

```
else if(orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >0 && <.10)
#Error: unexpected 'else' in "  else"
#     {
+      orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "low margin"
+   }

else if(orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >= .10 && < .25)
Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
```

> {orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "standard margin"}
>       else if(orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >= .50) 
>       Error: unexpected 'else' in " else"
>         {orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "high margin"}
>   }
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Instead of `orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >0 && < .10`, try `orders$profit_margin_flag[i] >0 && orders$profit_margin_flag[i] < .10`. Your `&& < .10` isn't valid syntax since `< .10` won't return a boolean (similar to the line below it).

Comment: That fixed the issue, thank you Mickey.

Comment: You should be using `cut`. It is much cleaner for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As @mickey pointed out, `&& < .10` isn't valid syntax.

That being said, do you want to replace `profit_margin_flag`'s value with "negative" etc. (as you specific in the OP) or do you want it assigned to a new variable?

I cleaned up your code a little bit (with the flag being assigned to a new variable `profit_margin_flag` and the margin values originally being stored in `profit_margin`) and this should work.

```
orders <- data.frame(profit_margin = c(-2, 0.07, 0.14, 11), profit_margin_flag = rep_len(NA, 4))

for(i in 1:nrow(orders)){
 +   if(orders$profit_margin[i] < 0){
 +     orders$profit_margin_flag[i] <- "negative"
 +   }
 +   else if(orders$profit_margin[i] > 0 && orders$profit_margin[i] < 0.10){
 +     orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "low margin"
 +   }
 +   else if(orders$profit_margin[i] >= 0.10 && orders$profit_margin[i] < 0.25)
 +   {
 +     orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "standard margin"
 +   }
 +   else if(orders$profit_margin[i] >= 0.50) 
 +   {
 +     orders$profit_margin_flag[i]<- "high margin"
 +   }
 + }

orders
#   profit_margin profit_margin_flag
# 1         -2.00           negative
# 2          0.07         low margin
# 3          0.14    standard margin
# 4         11.00        high margin
```